# Can you use multiple reference groups in a single logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, odds-ratio, categorical-encoding

When performing logistic regression for a binary categorical variable (i.e. 'gender', being `Male` or `Female` in this simple example) and some outcome (say `smoker` vs `nonsmoker`), you should dummy encode the categorical variable and then drop one column to avoid the dummy variable trap. As an example: dropping `Male`, this now becomes the reference group. The `Male` odds ratio is thus reported as 1, and the `Female` odds ratio is relative to the odds for the `Male` group.

If you include a second categorical variable in the logistic regression and do the same thing, do you then have two reference groups? Does this extend to as many categorical variables as you want?

Example: `Male` is dropped and is then a reference group (OR=1), and `Caucasian` is dropped, so becomes another reference group (OR also =1). `Female` OR is then relative to `Male`, and `Non-Caucasian` is then relative to `Caucasian`.

Comment: Are you asking if this can be done, are if this is what is done? If the latter, then no, all the reference groups are the first group, the intercept.

Comment: Both! In that case, how is one supposed to include more than a single categorical variable in a logistic regression? Is it possible? I think the words I was looking for are 'multivariate logistic regression' with dummy-encoded categorical variables. Thankyou @user2974951

Comment: The `model.matrix` function is great for studying the design matrix R creates with its default of using treatment contrasts. (You should not do the dummy encoding manually, most regression functions will do it for you.) Example: `DF <- data.frame(x1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B"), x2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c")); model.matrix(~ x1 + x2, data = DF)`

Comment: @lewiso1 That's what I said. If you include more than 1 categorical variable, then most implementations will use the first level of each categorical variable to create a single reference group. In your case the reference (intercept) will be Sex=Male and Ethnicity=Caucasian. With two additional terms for Sex=Female and Ethnicity=Other.

Comment: I see @user2974951 - so there is a single reference group with OR=1 that has the values of all the dropped columns (after dummy encoding). This seems functionally equivalent to multiple reference groups all with OR=1?

Comment: Thanks @Roland . There's a limit to subject tags, I'm actually running in statsmodels (python) but want a conceptual understanding first. I will try the model.matrix suggestion in R as well.

Comment: I don't know what OR is in your case. You should check the model.matrix output that  Roland mentioned, it should give you a clear look at what happens.